# How to kill the long grass in an established lawn?

Tags: lawn

How to kill long grass in an establish lawn?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I went to Home Depot, a stuff said there is no way to kill long grass. The way is to mow the lawn often.

Comment: Please clarify - are asking how to deal with a clump of long grass in an established lawn? Or are you asking how to get rid of it and its not part of a lawn?

Comment: 20-30 sheep should do if you want to kill it off. 2 or 3 would keep it short, guesstimating the area rather loosely.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - I have a few to spare. ^_^

Comment: @Bamboo, in my lawn. The picture just showed the edge of the lawn. There are a lot of in the middle of the lawn.

Comment: Looks like standard lawn ryegrass to me. Needs mowing before the seed heads form. And in the springtime grass growth is at its prime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've got clumps of grass in a lawn that grow faster and get taller than the rest of it, chances are it's an invader, a meadow or wild grass of some sort. Any total weedkiller will also kill your lawn grasses, and any weedkiller meant for lawns doesn't kill grass, so the best thing to do is dig out the clumps of taller grass, fill in the holes, level and reseed those parts. The only other alternative is to, as you say, cut it more often.

Comment: If you cut more often for a while, it will shift the balance of power to shorter types.