# how to kill weeds without chemicals in front yard and garden bed?

Tags: lawn, grass, weed-control, lawn-repair, roses

St Augustine grass in my front yard is healthy, Luscious and thick.  However there is one patch where weeds have taken over and keep expanding outward in 360 degrees.  I've tried smothering it with weedkiller fabric and cardboard for a month.  Also tried laying mulch over weeds in rose bushes.

- What is this weed? Is it crabgrass?
- Is a [propane weed torch or naturezap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbSa4wx4FJQ) the fastest way to kill these?

[Related Question #1](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24601/how-to-kill-the-long-grass-in-an-established-lawn)

[Related Question #2](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-do-i-kill-mile-a-minute-weed?rq=1)

**update:**  *Zoomed in photos added of St Augustine grass with weeds growing in it (bottom 3 photos with me holding it up)*

[image: looking toward house]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing any weeds; what I'm seeing is an area that's quite brown and fairly patchy, or just grass, together with some roses that might have been planted in pots plunged into the soil and which could do with some care and attention.. What weed are you referring to?

Comment: That looks like it could be damage from grubs. You could try lifting a 12" square about 3" deep from the browning area, then search through the soil for grubs. You might find a couple, which is okay, but any more than that indicates a problem.

Comment: @Bamboo i'lll upload a zoomed in photo to show differences. Perhaps the skinny plant is a type of grass, Roses are planted in ground.

Comment: @Danger14 Has this problem been resolved?

Comment: @Rob Unfortunately it has not.  I asked a local nursery and they think its crabgrass but are unsure.  I gave up and simply mow it shorter than rest of lawn.

Comment: This just looks like grass to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use vinegar, but to do that you need to know vinegar will also kill your plants. To use vinegar take a 2 liter bottle cut the end of it off. Have vinager in a spray bottle. Put the end of the 2 liter bottle over the weed and spray the vinegar into the neck of the bottle. That way the vinegar will get only on the weeds and not the other plants. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Angie. I tried that as well with no luck as these are too hardy and my area has constant rain to wash vinegar away.